# Android background Image to fill screen

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I get my relative layout to display my image view like this:

[image]

Instead of this?:

[image]

I want my layout to display as much of the image as it can and crop the outsides of the image, like when you're setting desktop background image to "Fill" in windows:

[image]

My xml layout so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:src="@drawable/background_race_light"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        style="@style/SessionResumeBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_resumeSessionBar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home_resumeSessionBar_buttonResume"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resume" />
    </LinearLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add a scale type to your imageview.  There are several types.  The one you need is

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

This [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) will help explain all the different types.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `ImageView` layout parameters to `match_parent` and set scale type to an appropriate scale type which fulfills your needs:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:src="@drawable/background_race_light"/>
```

Comment: `scale_type="center_crop"` is now `scaleType="centerCrop"`

Answer (score 0):

Set `scalexy = true` in `ImageView`