# Filling a background image to screen without changing aspect ratio

Tags: java, android

I'd like to display an image as a background for my activity, but would like to make it fill to screen without changing the aspect ratio of the image (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679366/android-background-image-to-fill-screen)).

I tried scaling the image, but that doesn't seem to work (because I'm using the image as a background, not defining it in an imageview, or so seems the problem).

How do I go about doing that? I even tried to define the background image in its own xml file, but that still didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you uses a RelativeLayout you can put a ImageView than fill all layout and put the rest over it. Something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    // Your full layout
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I actually just used it as part of the layout, and it worked nicely. I thought it would display the image as part of the layout, not as a background, but it didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only solution is the one with ImageView you mentioned. Why it is not appropriate for you? You can also use Bitmap.createBitmap() method to resize your bitmap do desired size.