# Imageview is not filling the entire layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

This is what I should do:

[image]

But this is what I am getting:

[image]

This is a small relevant part of my code:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        >

         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_scene_adress"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:paddingBottom="60dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="35dp" >   

       <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_image"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_scene_adress"
            style="@style/txt_adress_style"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_shape_source"
            android:text="adress" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is **shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/background_game" />
<padding  android:top="4dp"  android:bottom="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

As you can see the image-view is not filling the entire layout.Tried it a lot but could not find any solution.Help.

Comment: try android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: In the imageview use  android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Fit Center scales it so that the bigger of the two dimensions fills the width exactly, and the ratio of width to height remains uniform.  You want to use something else, likely centerCrop.  You want to keep the aspect ratio the same, but you want to completely fill the view-  that eliminates all of the fit types, and it means part of your image will be cropped out.

Comment: I'm saying that's the wrong one to use.  Its your problem.  Read the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.....

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_scene_adress"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="35dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" // use fill parent to have full width to fit in LinearLayout above
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_scene_adress"
        style="@style/txt_adress_style"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_shape_source"
        android:text="adress" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Reference: [Android background Image to fill screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679366/android-background-image-to-fill-screen?rq=1)