# Android center image and crop

Tags: java, android

im with a problem related to android UI Design.

This is what i want:
[http://i.imgur.com/a7DLo4x.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/a7DLo4x.jpg)

This is what i have:
[http://i.imgur.com/AnL3cHT.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/AnL3cHT.jpg)

I found a smiliar post about this, but their solution didnt help me:
[Android background Image to fill screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679366/android-background-image-to-fill-screen)

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" />


   <!-- <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/loginBt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Register"
        android:id="@+id/registerBt"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loginBt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/loginBt"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried to use android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong element to fill the ImageView. Please avoid using background element. Use src(source) element. It should then work fine.

```
 android:src
```

Comment: Ohh well a simple solution, you are the best, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you have 
     `android:scaleType="center"`

you need   `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: I know, i tried android:scaleType="centerCrop" too but didnt work tho

Comment: You are using android:backgroung instead of android:src. See the answer below